# Find out the recode change in column

Tags: sql, oracle

Emp table

```
ID  SALE_COM UPDATEDATE SALES_DT
4173 40      09-APR-2016  null
4173 40      20-SEP-2016  null
4173 30      06-OCT-2016  null
4173 30      14-OCT-2016  null
4073 50      23-DEC-2017  null
4073 40      01-JAN-2018  null
4073 40      14-OCT-2016  null
```

Emp_hist

```
EMP_ID  FIN_ID PRD_SEQ FIELD_VALUE     FIN_DATE
2167       13         4       30       28/09/14 
2055       11         3       30       01/09/15
```

Emp_detail

```
EMP_ID ID
4173   2167   30   06-OCT-2016  null
4073   2055   30   01-JAN-201  null
```

output Should be:

```
4173 40      09-APR-2016  null
4173 40      20-SEP-2016  null
4173 30      06-OCT-2016  28/09/14
4173 30      14-OCT-2016  null
4073 50      23-DEC-2017  null
4073 40      01-JAN-2018  01/09/15
4073 40      14-OCT-2016  null
```

Update query when our recode change in column

Comment: please demonstrate what you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will work for you:

```
SELECT
    E.ID,
    SALE_COM,
    UPDATEDATE,
    FIN_DATE
FROM
    EMP E
    LEFT JOIN EMP_DETAIL ED ON E.ID = ED.EMP_ID
                               AND E.UPDATEDATE = SOME_DATE
    LEFT JOIN EMP_HIST EH ON ED.ID = EH.EMP_ID
                             AND ED.FIELD_VALUE = EH.FIELD_VALUE
ORDER BY UPDATEDATE
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Here is the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0565d0e11fe09b69d5191d8bed70ffe)

Cheers!!